# Replacing part of strings with the index of the string in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
var <- c("b_express_xxx", "b_express_yy", "b_express_z")
```

I want to update the string after "express_" to be the index of the string in the vector. This is the desired output:

```
var_solution <- c("b_express_1", "b_express_2", "b_express_3")
```

How can I do this? I know I can use gsub, but I'm not sure how to replace it with different indices. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If they all have the same prefix, a quick way with `substr` would be to simply paste the prefix alongside the index (using `seq_along()`):

```
paste0(substr(var, 1, 10), seq_along(var))

[1] "b_express_1" "b_express_2" "b_express_3"
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `sub` and replacement groups

```
sub("(.*_).*(\\d+)", "\\1\\2", paste0(var, seq_along(var)))
[1] "b_express_1" "b_express_2" "b_express_3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by using `paste0` and `seq_along` to generate a new string based on the index of the string in the vector. Here's how you can do this,

```
# original vector
var <- c("b_express_xxx", "b_express_yy", "b_express_z")

# new strings
var_solution <- paste0("b_express_", seq_along(var))

print(var_solution)
```

`seq_along(var)` generates a sequence of numbers from 1 to the length of var.`paste0("b_express_", seq_along(var))` concatenates `"b_express_"` with each number in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all lowercase letters before the end of the string and then paste on the values.

```
paste0(gsub("[a-z]+$", "", var), seq_along(var))
```

This will work if your strings do not have the same "b_express" prefix:

```
var <- c("b_express_c_xxx", "b_anotherprefix_yy", "b_express_z")

paste0(gsub("[a-z]+$", "", var), seq_along(var))
# "b_express_c_1"     "b_anotherprefix_2" "b_express_3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stringr::str_replace_all(var, "[^_]+$", as.character(seq_along(var)))

[1] "b_express_1" "b_express_2" "b_express_3"
```

---

```
`regmatches<-`(var, regexpr("[^_]+$", var), value = seq_along(var))
[1] "b_express_1" "b_express_2" "b_express_3"
```

---

If you do not mind doing inplace replacement:

```
regmatches(var, regexpr("[^_]+$", var)) <- seq_along(var)
var
[1] "b_express_1" "b_express_2" "b_express_3"
```